# How to show temp data value on Index View after search button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

How can I show tempdata value on Index view after search button click is hit.

I tried but it does not work.

On Index.cshtml

I have this button

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-search">Search</button>
```

I have this below jquery code in Index.cshtml script tag

```
$('#btn-search').on('click', function () {
        //var data = { UserName: $('#txtusername').val(), Locality: $('#Locality').val() }
        var data = { UserName: $('#txtusername').val(), Locality: $('#Locality').val() }
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Report")',
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    });
```

In Report Controller on Search Action I am using this below function

```
 public ActionResult Search(string UserName, int? Locality)
        {
            TempData["Hello"] = "Hello";
            return View();
        }
```

And my expectation is to show `@TempData["Hello"]` on Index.cshtml

Comment: What is the view you are returning and what do you want to do with it? - You can access it in that view, but its not available in the response of you `success` callback (all you get there is the rendered html of the view)

Comment: So when ever i hit search button i want to see temp data hello in Index view

Comment: The add it to the view your returning and then append that to the DOM (but you have not shown what you doing in the `success: function (response) {` callback so its not clear what your doing

Comment: Success is blank.

Comment: Then why on earth are you returning a view if you don't do anything with it? And you might as well return a `JsonResult` and just add "Hello" to the DOM (`TempData` is pointless)

Comment: Is there a way to get tempdata in ajax success and use it in index view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177812/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sgl).

Comment: You cant get temp data value like this wihout post back. Please try with Web.API response.